# Backbone Filtering Collection and Dispaying

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection of , lets say 20 items... I want to filter my results and show 5 of them. Index at 5 to 9, lets say..

my html

```
{{#each myCol}} <br>
   <div id="{{this.controlName}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

so far my js

```
var myData = {
    myCol: this.collection.models
};

for ( var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    var newCol = this.collection.at(i);
}
```

so obviously, it is still drawing all the collection items, rather than index 5 to 9 which I wanted to happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `models` inside a collection is just an array so you can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var five_to_nine = this.collection.models.slice(5, 10);
```

Or you could throw a [`toArray`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) into the mix if you don't want to access the collection's `models` directly:

```
var five_to_nine = this.collection.toArray().slice(5, 10);
```

You could also add a `slice` method into your collection if you're doing this often:

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //...
    slice: function(begin, end) {
        return this.models.slice(begin, end);
    }
});
```

and then you could simply:

```
var five_to_nine = this.collection.slice(5, 10);
```

Your `five_to_nine` would be an array of models though so you'd have to `toJSON` them manually if your template needs that:

```
var json = _(five_to_nine).map(function(m) { return m.toJSON() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
var newCol = []
for ( var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    newCol.push(this.collection.at(i));
}
var myData = {
    myCol: newCol
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering collection using backbone the best approach is to fetch the collection and the return a subset filtered collection this will also make you code more reusable

To make the filter you should have a filtered function in your collection

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
  filtered : function ( min , max) {
```

I suggest to use UnderScore filter which will return true for valid and false for invalid where true is what you are looking for. use this.models to get the current collection models use model.get( '' ) to get the element you want to check for

```
    var results = _.filter( this.models, function ( model ) {           
        if ( model.get('index') >= min && model.get('index') <= max ) 
        return true ; 
        return false ;
    });
```

Then use underscore map your results and transform it to JSON like

```
    results = _.map( results, function( model ) { return model.toJSON()  } );
```

Finally returning a new backbone collection with only results

```
    return new Backbone.Collection( results ) ;
```

Optionally if you don't want to keep all the data in the collection but just the filtered one you should reset the collection and skip the above return like

```
    this.reset( results ) ;
```

**View** : call the filtered method and use render() on each of the item